# The best practices for keeping the change table rows

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need to know  the best way for keeping the change of a table rows.
So I have article table (ArticleId,Designation,Price), the price  change every year and I need to keep the previous value(in 2015 = 500$ and in 2016 = 600$), I propose to create another table  ArticleHistory with the some structure and insert the copy of row article with the new value or save the new value in a new row , especially knowing that article table count more than 5000 rows.

Comment: You may looking for update trigger

Comment: Thanks but sorry i want to know if I save the article with a new price in another table or insert a new row in the some table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a history table is a good option and you can use an [after update update trigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) on your Article table to insert the rows in the history table..

Another option is to use [Change Data Capture](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1474/using-change-data-capture-cdc-in-sql-server-2008/).